# How to define multy inheritance in Android Java

Tags: java, android

I have two errors in my manig=fest which I don't understand, I hope some one can help me.
The errors in my manifest are both errors related the activity: `<activity android:name=".PersonListAdapter"/>`

The errors are:

1. its class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)
2. PersonListAdapter must extend android.app.Activity - Regarding this error: How can I define that class extend from another class and from Android app?

Here is my code:
manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="co.il.applicationmoran">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".register">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".peoplefinder"/>

        <activity android:name=".PersonListAdapter"/>

        <activity android:name=".login"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Class

```
package co.il.applicationmoran;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PersonListAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<person>  {
    private static String TAG = "PersonListAdapter";
    private Context mycontext;
    int myresource;

    public PersonListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<person> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mycontext = context;
        this.myresource=resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
        String name = getItem(position).getName();
        String age=getItem(position).getAge();
        String sex=getItem(position).getSex();

        person person=new person(name,age,sex);
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(mycontext);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(myresource, parent, false);

        TextView tvName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        TextView tvAge=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        TextView tvSex=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview3);

        tvName.setText(name);
        tvAge.setText(age);
        tvSex.setText(sex);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Java naming conventions have class names starting with a capital letter (Person rather than person).

Comment: Hi - capital letter is convention , it doesn't cause errors.

Comment: I know that. I commented because I misunderstood the code until I figured out your misuse of the convention. It is a rather important convention.

Answer (score 0):

1. A public constructor with no arguments can be added as:

> public PersonListAdapter() {
> }

2. The adapter class doesn't need to be mentioned in the manifest file, you mostly mention activity and service classes in the manifest. Remove below lines from the manifest file:

> ```
> <activity android:name=".peoplefinder"/> //remoe if this is also not an activity class
>
> <activity android:name=".PersonListAdapter"/> //remove
>
> <activity android:name=".login"/> //remove if this is also not an activity class
> ```

Comment: Hi they are activities - but without errors so I didn't put them here.